# HttpUrlConnect.getInputStream() confusion

Tags: java, php

In my application, I make this http connection.

```
String first = params[1];
String last = params[2];
String email = params[3];
String password = params[4];
URL url = new URL(register_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("first","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(first,"UTF-8")+"&"
        +URLEncoder.encode("last","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(last,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")
        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
bufferedWriter.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
outputStream.close();
InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
String result="";
String line="";
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
    result += line;
}
```

Above code connects to the php file in the remote server

```
<?php 
require "conn.php";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from arsenal_data where email like '$email' and      password like '$password';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo " Remote login success!";
}
else {
echo " Remote login fails!";
}

?>
```

My question is why is "Remote login success!" in the echo statement in the php file in the result of htttpURLConnect.getInputStream()? I assume that "echo" statement in php file is just displaying a message? What is the difference with this and $_GET["String"]in php file? Both methods are sending message from the php file in the server to the client?

Comment: "echo" writes to the HTTP response. That's how PHP Works.

Comment: What is the difference between echo and $_get in php file? Both send data from the server to the client? @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP the `$_GET` variable holds the query parameter from the HTTP Request that was sent TO the PHP server.  So it is an "input".   `echo` is used to send text back in a the HTTP Response body, so it is an "output".